# WSO2: Update roles of user via web services

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I've install a WSO2 API-M and try to update the roles of a user.

My request body:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsd="http://org.apache.axis2/xsd">
   <soap:Header/>
   <soap:Body>
      <xsd:addRemoveRolesOfUser>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <xsd:userName>tom</xsd:userName>
         <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
         <xsd:newRoles>internal/subscriber</xsd:newRoles>
         <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
         <xsd:deletedRoles>admin</xsd:deletedRoles>
      </xsd:addRemoveRolesOfUser>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

My response:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <soapenv:Fault>
            <soapenv:Code>
                <soapenv:Value>soapenv:Receiver</soapenv:Value>
            </soapenv:Code>
            <soapenv:Reason>
                <soapenv:Text xml:lang="en-US">Error occurred while getting
                    database type from DB connection</soapenv:Text>
            </soapenv:Reason>
            <soapenv:Detail />
        </soapenv:Fault>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I try to only delete role is okay, but fail to add new roles.

Is there any one know what's happened?

2016.08.23 updated:

The request of updateRolesOfUser:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsd="http://org.apache.axis2/xsd">
   <soap:Header/>
   <soap:Body>
      <xsd:updateRolesOfUser>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <xsd:userName>?</xsd:userName>
         <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
         <xsd:newRoleList>?</xsd:newRoleList>
      </xsd:updateRolesOfUser>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Thanks

Tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you should send the requests to successfully add/update/delete user roles.

**To add and delete roles in the same response:**

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://org.apache.axis2/xsd">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <xsd:addRemoveRolesOfUser>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <xsd:userName>Tom</xsd:userName>
         <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
         <xsd:newRoles>admin</xsd:newRoles>
         <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
         <xsd:deletedRoles>test</xsd:deletedRoles>       
      </xsd:addRemoveRolesOfUser>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

**To only add new roles (remove deletedRoles element):**

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://org.apache.axis2/xsd">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <xsd:addRemoveRolesOfUser>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <xsd:userName>Tom</xsd:userName>
         <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
         <xsd:newRoles>admin</xsd:newRoles>       
      </xsd:addRemoveRolesOfUser>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

**To update new roles:**

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://org.apache.axis2/xsd">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <xsd:updateRolesOfUser>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <xsd:userName>Tom</xsd:userName>
         <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
         <xsd:newRoleList>test</xsd:newRoleList>
         <xsd:newRoleList>admin</xsd:newRoleList>
         <xsd:newRoleList>Internal/subscriber</xsd:newRoleList>
      </xsd:updateRolesOfUser>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

**Note:** If it says zero or more repetitions, remove the entire element if you are not passing any value

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Could you either try updateRolesOfUser? I'll post above. The error will be the same.Thank you so much.

Comment: Tried updateRolesOfUser. It works when only one role is added in the new role list. May I know your exact requirement?

Comment: My requirement is : Admin can change the roles of users via web services API.  My API-M version is 1.10.0. I tried updateRolesOfUser but fail, so I try addRemoveRolesOfUser...it also failed.

Comment: I create a user and assign admin to the user and then I try to use updateRolesOfUser with new role "sub-admin" I'd created to update the roles of the user, and...it get the same error.